# Camera imported from alembic does not follow it's parent transformations in 2.79?

Tags: animation, camera, import, versions, alembic

I came across a problem when i was working with blender files created in older versions of blender. I currently use 2.79.

In those scenes i have a camera sequence imported with alembic format. I moved this camera around by parenting it to locator, and moving the locator.

Problem is: in this version of blender, alembic camera sequence does not follow the parent movement at all. The camera got it's position reset in those scenes as if it was never parented and moved. I tested it in fresh blender scene, newly imported .abc camera does not move with it's parent, and stays in 1 place.

Is there a way to fix this and make camera respect transformation of it's parent again?

Comment: Is the  locator also imported?  If so is the camera a child of locator in import?

Comment: No, locator is created inside new scene from scratch. No parent is imported with camera.

Comment: Please write a bug report at https://developer.blender.org and tag it with Alembic.